# Flutter: I can't add Bluetooth printer devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

I am using bluetooth_print package. I have tried two or three other packages also. But don't know why I can't make it work. The bluetooth scan doesn't even find nearby devices. I have added the android permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml files.

Here's my code for bluetooth_print package. It basically is the same code in the package documentation:

https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print/example